# Fixing dynamic linker errors when using libc with openssl

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, musl

Here's a simple hello world sha1-hasher that's using the openssl library.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("printf '%s' 'hello world' | sha1sum");

    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char digest_pr[(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH)*2+1];
    SHA_CTX ctx;
    if(!SHA1_Init(&ctx)) return 1;
#define STR_STRLEN(A) A, (sizeof(A)/sizeof(*(A))-1)
    if(!SHA1_Update(&ctx,STR_STRLEN("hello"))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(!SHA1_Update(&ctx,STR_STRLEN(" world"))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(!SHA1_Final(digest,&ctx)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    #define DIGITS "0123456789abcdef"
    for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(digest);i++){
        digest_pr[i*2+0]=DIGITS[digest[i]/16];
        digest_pr[i*2+1]=DIGITS[digest[i]%16];
    }
    digest_pr[(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH)*2]='\0';
    puts(digest_pr);
}
```

On a Mint/Ubuntu with libssl-dev installed, I can compile and link it with `$CC sha.c` (where CC is one of gcc, tcc, or clang) and then successfully run it, but this didn't work with musl so I grabbed the openssl source (`git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl`), configured it with `./config --prefix=/usr/local/musl`, built it and installed it and now `musl-gcc sha.c -lcrypto works` but running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/musl/lib a.out` gets me:

```
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: makecontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: setcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __memcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __strcat_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: secure_getenv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __syslog_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __memset_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __fread_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: getcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/musl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that libcrypto in /usr/local/musl was built with musl-gcc?

Comment: @arved Thanks. Looks like I was doing `./config ... && CC=musl-gcc make` when it should've been `CC=musl-gcc ./config ... && make`. But now it won't build because of an ENOENT on `<linux/mman.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your OpenSSL is **not built against musl-libc**.

The musl-libc has its own dynamic linker (see https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq.html), we could create a soft link for the musl dynamic linker. (`-syslibdir` is the directory in which the dynamic library, e.g. `ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`, is, see https://wiki.musl-libc.org/getting-started.html)

```bash
sudo ln -sf <YOUR-MUSL-LIBC-syslibdir/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1> /usr/bin/musl-ldd
```

Then you could see whether openssl is built against musl-libc. When I build OpenSSL using glibc, it shows the following error

```bash
$ musl-ldd <YOUR-OPENSSL-SRC>/libcrypto.so.1.1
        musl-ldd (0x7fcd5a749000)
        libdl.so.2 => musl-ldd (0x7fcd5a749000)
        libpthread.so.0 => musl-ldd (0x7fcd5a749000)
        libc.so.6 => musl-ldd (0x7fcd5a749000)
Error relocating ./libcrypto.so.1.1: makecontext: symbol not found
Error relocating ./libcrypto.so.1.1: setcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating ./libcrypto.so.1.1: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating ./libcrypto.so.1.1: getcontext: symbol not found
```

And the glib dynamic linker works fine,

```bash
$ ldd <YOUR-OPENSSL-SRC>/libcrypto.so.1.1
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd395a6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff6e6e64000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6e6e41000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6e6c4f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6e71d7000)
```

To build OpenSSL using musl-libc, we have to also specify the location of linux headers to avoid errors like `<linux/mman.h>`

I only have attempted to build OpenSSL using Clang and Musl-libc, here is the clang wrapper I used https://gist.github.com/randoruf/d1aa4e8acb0a852addcd2b84fc003719.

> (taken from https://qiita.com/kakinaguru_zo/items/399ab7ea716a56aef50c which is written by kakinaguru_zo)

But **there are still a few issues in the clang-wrapper**.

This wrapper will link the startfile (`e.g. Scrt1.o`) regardless of building libraries or executables. Apparently, only executables need startfile. Hence, if you use this wrapper, you may encounter the following strange error (`main` symbol not found):

```
$ musl-clang mylibrary.c -shared -fPIC -o libmylibrary.so
$ musl-ldd libmylibrary.so
        ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f49faef7000)
        libc.so => ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f49faef7000)
Error relocating libmylibrary.so: main: symbol not found
```

If the library has the startfile, it may have an entry to `main`. This is the reason why the `main` symbol is not found.

The solution is not to include startfile for shared libraries (the new clang wrapper should fix the problem).

Another issue is that `test_errstr`, `test_ca`, `test_ssl_new` will not pass due to the fact that the operating system and its software are built against glibc.

Details are posted on my blog https://randoruf.github.io/2022/08/23/musl-libc-ubuntu.html#about-the-test-case-in-openssl

The final issue is that this wrapper only supports c language. Another wrapper may be helpful see https://github.com/esjeon/musl-clang/blob/master/musl-clang